# API usage "Try It" form for linked questions queries meta.tex.stackexchange instead of Stackoverflow

Tags: bug, status-completed

I was wondering why the form at http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/usage/methods/linked-questions did not return the questions I was expecting.  Then I noticed that it is calling `http://api.meta.tex.stackexchange.com/1.1/questions/{id}/linked` instead of querying Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been fixed.

Rather than baking the query url into the docs (and having to deal with caching issues), we're just pulling it in javascript now.